# Add extra classpath to executors in Spark client mode

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark 1.5.1 with the standalone cluster manager. Spark's default `spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar` includes Avro 1.7.7. I want to use my custom Avro library for all my Spark jobs, let's call it Avro 1.7.8. This works perfectly in dev mode (master=local[*]). However, when I submit my app to the cluster in client mode, the executors still use Avro 1.7.7 library.

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(GenericData.class.getName().replace('.','/')+".class");
```

When I print this, my executor's log shows :

> /opt/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.class

Here is a part of my spark-env.sh on the worker node :

```
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/ansible/avro-1.7.8.jar -Dspark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true
```

Here is my worker process on the worker node (`ps aux | grep worker`) :

> spark       955  1.8  1.9 4161448 243600 ?      Sl   13:29   0:09 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/java -cp /home/ansible/avro-1.7.8.jar:/etc/spark-worker/:/opt/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar  -Dspark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/ansible/avro-1.7.8.jar -Dspark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://spark-a-01:7077

Obviously, I put this jar : `/home/ansible/avro-1.7.8.jar` in all my worker nodes.

Does anyone knows how to force the executor to use my jar instead of the spark assembly's one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--packages` option to `spark-submit`:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.8 ....
```

Something like that. If you're not using `spark-submit`, use it -- this is exactly what it is for.

Comment: I'm actually running my app in deploy mode "client" from SBT, using `sparkConf.setMaster("spark://....")`. The equivalent of what you say in my case is : `sparkConf.setJars(Seq("file://home/tmouron/avro-1.7.8.jar"))`. But I have the same problem with this additional line : avro-1.7.7 is being used.